# Is there a way to generate a user id for android?

Tags: android, android-studio, implementation, userid

Is there a way to generate a user id for new users like 'yik yak' does, removing the need of a login id and password? i really want to implement this as the app i am creating is not e-commerce so there is no need for such tight security. 
Also would there be a way to display the generated user so users could add each other as friends?

Comment: probably you can take the advantage of mobile number.This will help user to add other user.

Comment: i thought about this but in terms of privacy you might not want every user to have your mobile numder

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about a user ID, but I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2853253/1236581) to generate a device specific ID for similar purposes to what your are describing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this using the faker library: https://www.bloco.io/blog/2015/faker-a-library-to-generate-fake-data-for-java-android

Please follow their tutorial.